# convert yyyymm on factor class to character class to be used with ChartSeries()

Tags: r, csv, xts, quantmod

I read a CSV file using `read.csv()` command and I want to convert into xts and graph with `chartSeries()`.

I changed into a matrix by doing:

```
MyData <- as.matrix(MyData)
```

When I convert to xts using

```
MyData_xts <- xts(MyData[,-1], order.by=as.POSIXct(MyData[,1]))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The column that has my index is in the yyyymm format.  I've read that that may be a problem, but I haven't been able to find a way around it.

**EDIT 1**

The CSV read before converting to matrix looks like this. All of the rows are factors class:

```
 X     |Mkt.RF|SMB
 ------|------|---
 196307|-0.39 |-.046
 196308|5.07  |-0.81
 196308|-1.57 |-.048
```

Comment: bethanyP, when converting to matrix the class for all the fields convert from factor to character.

Comment: G5W, when converting to xts NA's are created in the database.  I know they are not there before because im using omit.na() to eliminate all the rows with NAs prior to converting to xts.  But after converting to xts and running chartSeries() I get the following error: Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type

Comment: Please provide a sample of your CSV file.

Comment: @Yago  I updated my answer to use your data and respond to your comment

Answer (score 2):

You should use `read.zoo` to import your CSV directly into a zoo object. If you want, you can use `as.xts` to convert the zoo object to xts. You should also use a `yearmon` index, since your index only has years and months.

```
Text <- "X,Mkt.RF,SMB
196307,-0.39,-0.046
196308, 5.07,-0.810
196309,-1.57,-0.048"

# function adapted from examples in ?read.zoo
z <- read.zoo(text=Text, header=TRUE, sep=",",
              FUN=function(x) as.yearmon(format(x), "%Y%m"))
z
#          Mkt.RF    SMB
# Jul 1963  -0.39 -0.046
# Aug 1963   5.07 -0.810
# Sep 1963  -1.57 -0.048
```

Comment: I'm new to R.  I don't fully understand the code you provided,in particular why x/100 in as.yearmon().  I'm getting the following error message:   Error in x/100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Yago: that part isn't necessary, and I've edited it out of my answer.  You probably got that error because there are lines in your CSV where the first column cannot be interpreted as numeric. If that's true, you need to look carefully at the data in the CSV to determine how to handle those rows.

Comment: Joshua, you were right.  I had a data issue in one of my rows in the original CSV file.  The code works now.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any data,  I will use a small test example that matches your description. I do not think that `as.POSIXct` will work without specific days. You can make this work by using the first day of each month.

```
x = c("201701", "201702", "201703")
xt = as.POSIXct(paste(x, "01", sep=""), format="%Y%m%d")
xts(xt, order.by=xt)
                 [,1]
2017-01-01 1483246800
2017-02-01 1485925200
2017-03-01 1488344400
```

**Updated:**
I see that you have now provided data and say that you are getting NAs. I am using the data that you provided, reading it as a csv, processing it with my code and not getting NAs.  Please look again at this version of the code.

```
Input = read.csv(text="X,Mkt.RF,SMB
 196307,-0.39 ,-.046
 196308,5.07  ,-0.81
 196308,-1.57 ,-.048",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(xts)
Input$xt = as.POSIXct(paste(Input$X, "01", sep=""), format="%Y%m%d")
xts(Input, order.by=Input$xt)
           X        Mkt.RF  SMB      xt          
1963-07-01 "196307" "-0.39" "-0.046" "1963-07-01"
1963-08-01 "196308" " 5.07" "-0.810" "1963-08-01"
1963-08-01 "196308" "-1.57" "-0.048" "1963-08-01"
```

Comment: G5W thank you for your response.  I reviewed the code you submitted and still getting NAs after running xts().  I'm able to generate the index ok, but when running xts() and then periodicity() I get the following error message: can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation