# When converting date column to be used as index in xts object, the resulting xts object generates NAs

Tags: r, csv, xts, quantmod

I read the following CSV using `read.csv()` command and I want to convert into xts.
This is an example of the CSV output (class is factors):

```
  X    |Mkt.RF|SMB
 ------|------|---
 196307|-0.39 |-.046
 196308|5.07  |-0.81
 196308|-1.57 |-.048
```

Since the X column is in yyyymm format I used the following code to transform to the appropriate format:

```
 Date= as.Date(paste(MyData[,1], "01", sep=""), format="%Y%m%d")
```

Then I created my xts object:

```
 MyData_xts<-as.xts(MyData[,-1], order.by=Date)
```

When I try to look at the periodicity using

```
 periodicity(MyData_xts)
```

I get the following error message:  Error in periodicity(MyData_xts) : 
  can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation

I tried changing the date format to POSIXct class but that won't work.  Any guidance is appreciated.  Thank you.

Session Information:

```
 sessionInfo()
 R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
 Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United   States.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
 [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] quantmod_0.4-7 TTR_0.23-1     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-14    

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tools_3.3.2     grid_3.3.2      lattice_0.20-34
```

Comment: As I said in [a comment on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616109/convert-yyyymm-on-factor-class-to-character-class-to-be-used-with-chartseries#comment72421369_42636894) to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42616109/271616), there's at least one unusual row in your CSV.  You need to find it and either fix it or account for it in your code.